# Position text in matplotlib with date as axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to position text using the .text() method in matplotlib. My x-axis is formatted as datetime64. It works as advertised, but I nevertheless get an error as shown below.

My code:

```
fix, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.text('2014-11-01', 82, 'Text goes here', fontsize=26, weight='bold', alpha=.8)
plt.text('2014-11-01', 77, s= 'Subtitle text goes here', fontsize=18)
```

Which returns a plot as expected:
[plot with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeDah.png)

In addition, an error is raised:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

I'm quite confused by this. I also tried passing in a number through matplotlib's dates.date2num(t) method, but that wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass to `.text()` the coordinates **before** the actual text you want to insert. For example:

```
>>> text(0.5, 0.5,'matplotlib', horizontalalignment='center',
...      verticalalignment='center',
...      transform=ax.transAxes)
```

The error you're getting is caused by passing a string (`'2014-11-01'`) where the method expects a number.

See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text).

Comment: I did pass x and y coordinates. The x coordinate is simply a date, as the x-axis is formatted as a date.

Using any number that is logical for a date returns a chart that is too large to display. Hence I tried a date to number method. How would I pass a number to .text() when the x-axis is formatted as a date?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but since this post is listed on the first page on Google, I post my solution for anybody looking for the answer.

```
############################################################# 
# Write text to a datetime plot
#
# ax: axis where to plot
# date: string or datetime as x coordinate
# y_relative: relative y coordinate in 0,1 range
# text: label to plot
# kwargs: other arguments to pass to plt.text()

def date_text(ax, date, y_relative, text, **kwargs):
    # Transform date to float
    if type(date) == str:
        date = datestr2num(date)
    else:
        date = date2num(date)
    # Compute relative position in axis
    lims = ax.get_xlim()
    x_relative = (date-lims[0])/(lims[1]-lims[0])
    
    if abs(x_relative) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Date not in range")
    # Plot text
    ax.text(x_relative, y_relative, text, transform=ax.transAxes, **kwargs)
```

It is used this way:

```
index = pd.to_datetime(["2021-01-01", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-08"])
values = [1, 5, 8]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ["values", ], index = index)


plt.plot(df, marker='o')
date_text(plt.gca(), "2021-01-03", 0.9, "Some text over here", horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=17)
date_text(plt.gca(), "2021-01-06", 0.1, "And some vertical text over there", color="red", rotation="vertical", fontsize=10)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[This is the plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiGZe.png)